# Traveling within EU with expired Blue Card but a valid passport

Tags: resident-permit, blue-card, schengen, europe

I am a national of Turkey with a valid passport, working in Latvia with a Blue Card that is valid until **4th of December**. I already applied for the renewal of BC but it will take some time before I can get the new card.

I was planning a trip in **EU/Schengen** at the end of December but now have doubts that I might face a problem with the travel if the new card doesn't arrive until said time.

The Latvian migration office states that the lawful stay period after expiration of BC is 90 days. But I don't know if this also provides a seamless travel within EU/Schengen. Would I face any border problems if I were to travel with just my passport and current BC before I obtain my new Blue Card?

Comment: Do you have any temporary document, proof that you applied for renewal, etc.?

Comment: @Relaxed yes actually, I have a form sent by the migration affairs stating that I have applied for renewal of residence permit at a certain date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I face any border problems if I were to travel with just my passport and current BC before I obtain my new Blue Card?

Since you would be traveling with an **expired** residence permit, you could encounter problems if checked.

Only a **valid residence permit** exempts you, as a Turkish citizen, from the visa requirement for other Schengen countries.

> **Schengen Borders Code Article 6 (1)(b)**:
> they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 ( 1 ), **except where they hold a valid residence permit** or a valid long-stay visa;

Comment: (+1) Your advice is sound but the legal basis is probably to be found in national law of each country. Article 6 isn't really about that, as it pertains to entry at external borders (cf. the heading of Title II), not to internal borders (which are dealt with in Title III) and only implicitly with stay (rules there are much more complex).

Comment: @Relaxed This is delt with in: [Schengen Convention Article 21](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=celex:42000A0922(02)) and seems to the latest verion, but references the outdated *Article 5(1)(a), (c) and (e) of Regulation (EC) No 562/2006* (which is now *Article 6 of REGULATION (EU) 2016/399*) and 3 months instead of 90/180 days. I couldn't find anything newer, which seems odd.